# How to decrease the distance for launcher icon in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-launcher, android-icons

My **Launcher** icon has the same size as the default launcher icon. But its very far away from the left side on **`ActionBar`**. Is there anyway , how can i decrease this distance. Icon Sizes for my `Launcher` are :

- **MDPI should be 48 x 48.**
- **HDPI should be 72 x 72.**
- **XHDPI should be 96 x 96.**
- **XXHDPI should be 144 x 144.**

[image]

**EDITED :** Styles for my Action Bar

```
<style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/overflow_menu_icon</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#0099cc</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#33b5e5</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_style</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you set a custom up indicator? The up indicator is what pushes the app icon to the right.

Comment: no no no, ,,,its not the indicator, the black line is just to highlight. There is no indicator.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the indicator is visible or not, as long as you set a custom one the app icon will always be pushed to the right by the indicator. So  are you sure that you did not set a custom indicator? Remember doesn't matter if the indicator is visible, all it takes is for the theme of the `Activity` too have a custom indicator.

Comment: I am not using the custom up indicator icon neither i have created one.

Comment: Are you setting a custom view? And could you show us the styles of your `ActionBar`?

Comment: I have edited my question , and as for the ActionBar customisation is concerned then i am just customising the its background color.